# Ext JS - get value of toggleGroup when default type is button

Tags: extjs

How to get value of toggleGroup when default type is button. 
allowblank:false is also not working.

```
 {
        xtype:'radiogroup',
        fieldLabel: 'What is your title?',
        layout:'hbox',
        allowBlank:false,
        defaultType: 'button',      
        id: 'titleSel',
        defaults: {
            enableToggle: true,
            toggleGroup: 'titleGroup',
            allowDepress: false,
            width: '16.56%',
            name: 'title',
        },                      
        items: [
            {text: 'Mr', value: 'Mr', inputValue: 'sfsf'},
            {text: 'Mrs', value: 'Mrs'},
            {text: 'Madam', value: 'Madam'},
            {text: 'Ms', value: 'Ms'},
            {text: 'Dr', value: 'Dr'},
            {text: 'Prof', value: 'Prof'},          
            ],
        },
```

Comment: have you tried getChecked() on RadioGroup?

Comment: getChecked() is not returning any value. I am able to get value on submit button when I remove - defaultType: 'button'. Basically I am trying to change the radio look n feel as button.

Comment: Ext.getCmp('titleSel').getChecked() -- Not returning any value.

Comment: Ext.getCmp('titleSel').getValue() is returning value as [object Object]

Comment: Is it really a requirement that your group works with Buttons? That is not returning anyvalues because buttons are not formFields meaning that it won't return any value on formSubmit

Answer (score 0):

in ExtJS 5.x... you'll have to extend class `Ext.container.ButtonGroup` and then bind the buttons' default handler to a custom change event listener... which gets either the name or id passed.

```
Ext.define('SomeApp.view.toggle.Titles', {
    extend: 'Ext.container.ButtonGroup',
    alias: ['widget.ToggleTitles'],
    frameHeader: true,
    title: false,
    columns: 6,
    width: 300,
    height: 46,
    border: 0,

    defaults: {
        enableToggle: true,
        toggleGroup: 'titles',
        handler: function(){
            this.up('buttongroup').fireEvent('change', this.name.replace('btn', '').toLowerCase());
        }
    },

    items: [
        {tabIndex: 1, name: 'btnMr',    text: 'Mr', pressed: true},
        {tabIndex: 2, name: 'btnMrs',   text: 'Mrs'},
        {tabIndex: 3, name: 'btnMadam', text: 'Madam'},
        {tabIndex: 4, name: 'btnMs',    text: 'Ms'},
        {tabIndex: 5, name: 'btnDr',    text: 'Dr'},
        {tabIndex: 6, name: 'btnProf',  text: 'Prof'}
    ],

    listeners: {
        change: function(value){
           ...
        }
    }

}
```